# How to set static IP after smart config on esp8266

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm using Esptouch for smart config WiFi on Esp8266. I did change IP to static IP but I didn't connect. So Does anyone have any ideas to help me? Sorry my English is not good

```
 const IPAddress&  demo = WiFi.localIP();

 //setup getway
 int gateway0 = int(demo[0]);
 int gateway1 = int(demo[1]);
 int gateway2 = int(demo[2]);
 int gateway3 = 1;
 IPAddress gateway(gateway0,gateway1,gateway2,gateway3);

 //setup ip
 IPAddress ip(gateway0, gateway1, gateway2, 233);

 //setup subnet
 IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
 WiFi.config(ip,gateway,subnet);
 Serial.println("");
 Serial.println("WiFi connected");
 Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you want to change the local IP when your ESP is in AP_STA (or AP) mode.

If yes, add this to your code:

```
IPAddress local_IP(192, 168, 10,11);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 4, 9);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
WiFi.softAPConfig(local_IP, gateway, subnet);
WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);`//change the SSID and password
```

You can change the values, local_IP is what you'll get if you execute WiFi.localIP().

Comment: Hi Juraj , I'm using in STA mode . I disconnected  WiFi and reconnect. After that, this code ran. thanks you.